# Task : Need to develop Mini Bank Application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Today I went Interview to Cleartrip software company. First round programming, we need to build a mini bank application.

In question paper they were clearly mentioned, no data persistence required.

1. Create an account
2. Deposit money
3. Withdraw money, honor daily withdrawal limit.
4. Check the balance

This is what I did my own, I was getting rejected.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateAccount {
    int accountid;
    String accountantname;
    String IFSCcode;

   public CreateAccount(int accountid,String accountantname,String IFSCcode){
    this.accountid = accountid;
    this.accountantname = accountantname;
    this.IFSCcode = IFSCcode;
   }

    /*//adding deposit money with the balance 
    public double despositMoney() throws MiniumAmountDeposit{

        double Currentbalance = 0.00;
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the deposit amount");
        double Depositamount = scn.nextDouble();
        Currentbalance += Depositamount ;
        System.out.println("your currentbalance="+Currentbalance);

        return Currentbalance;
    }*/

    //withdrawl money  and set daily withdrawl limit
    public void WithdrawMoney() throws InsufficientBalException, MiniumAmountDeposit{


        double Currentbalance = 0.00;
        Scanner deposit = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the deposit amount");
        double Depositamount = deposit.nextDouble();
        Currentbalance += Depositamount ;
        System.out.println("your currentbalance="+Currentbalance);

        /*double Currentbalanace = despositMoney();*/

        //setDaily Withdrawl limit
           final double setDailyLimit = 2500.00;     

            Scanner withDraw = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("please enter the withdraw amount");
            double WithdrawMoney =withDraw.nextDouble();


        if(Currentbalance < WithdrawMoney)
            System.out.println("you have less amount : your current balance is="+Currentbalance);

        else if (WithdrawMoney > setDailyLimit)
            System.out.println("you have entered amount exceed than daily limit : your dailyLimit="+setDailyLimit);

        else 
            Currentbalance -= WithdrawMoney;
            System.out.println("your current balance is="+Currentbalance);

    }


    /*public void setWithdrawlLimit()throws exceedLimit{
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the withdraw amount");
           double  enterAmount = scn.nextDouble();
        double DailysetLimit = 2500;

        if(enterAmount>DailysetLimit)
            System.out.println("you have exceed daily limit : your dailyLimit"+DailysetLimit);


    }*/

    public String toString(){

        return "accountid="+this.accountid + "accountantname="+this.accountantname + "IFSCcode="+this.IFSCcode;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        CreateAccount account = new CreateAccount(1234455533,"samy","ICIC09");
        System.out.println("you have created account : " +account);
    /*  
        try {
            account.despositMoney();
        } catch (MiniumAmountDeposit e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        try {
            account.WithdrawMoney();
        } catch (InsufficientBalException | MiniumAmountDeposit e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*try {
            account.setWithdrawlLimit();
        } catch (exceedLimit e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

*/      
    }

}
```

someone can tell me what's wrong with this approach.

Comment: Try posting it there https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would suggest you to read Clean Code by Robert C. Martin.

Comment: @Bentaye I post my question over here codereview.stackexchange.com people are responding when I try to reply them back it shows "to add comment 50 reputation need"

Comment: Maybe you can edit your answer there instead of posting a comment. But you will definitely get better feedback there than here.

Comment: I meant edit your question